# jQuery Validate layout issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I am using jQuery Validate to validate my form. I have been hard coding the error labels and using Validate to show/hide the labels. I've been hard coding them because I needed to override the default styling of jQuery Validate to display as "inline-block" not "inline".

I now need to show 2 different error messages depending on the validation state, a "general" one and a "must not exceed 6 characters" one. It currently works but the second error message is generated and is not styled correctly so it breaks the layout.

Is there a way of determining which hard coded error label to show depending on which error state jQuery Validation picks up?

(PS:If anyone can tell me how to override the styling of the generated error label, that will solve my problem too)

My hard coded label looks like this:

```
<label for="registration" class="error" style="display:inline-block; margin:5px 0 0 130px;">Please enter valid registration</label>
```

I need to hard code a second one but find a way to differentiate between the 2, and only show this when it is neccessary:

```
<label for="registration" class="error" style="display:inline-block; margin:5px 0 0 130px;">Please enter no more than 6 characters</label>
```

Comment: wouldn't `form label.error{ display: inline-block !important; }` work?

Comment: You don't need to hardcode anything to override the style. Just override the styles through CSS.

Comment: Thanks guys, those suggestions would have worked but I needed a way to style those error labels differently from the others in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by adding a different class to the error class for that one input field. By doing this it allowed me to style those error messages differently from the other error messages generated by the form.

JavaScript - this gets added to your current validate function

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     if(element.attr("id") == 'username'){ // match your element's id
          error.addClass("errorclass"); // add invalid class
          error.appendTo(element.parent()); // this line willchange depends on your form layout
     else{
          error.appendTo(element.parent()); // this line willchange depends on your form layout
          }
```